# How to determine the typical life (in hours/minutes) of a 9V?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

I'm really struggling on how to calculate battery drain. So I have a 9V battery hooked up to a motor (12V) and resistor inbetween. The motor gets around 3.50~V mostly.

How do I determine the lifespan of a typical 9V battery based on this? I know that a 9V has 500mah~ give or take. I know I must be missing something. Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Update: Thanks to [Reddit /r/AskElectronics](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/6hufz9/how_to_determine_the_typical_life_in_hoursminutes/) I understand how to calculate this and I also learned that a 9V is a poor choice for what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: Don't even bother.  The design you describe is a very poorly thought out.  If your goal is to apply something in the range of 3.5 volts to a motor, re-design around say 3 AA cells, and if you need to limit the motor further use a PWM controller to efficiently use the energy in the battery to accomplish your goal, without wasting most of it in a resistor as you would be with the excessive 9v input.

Comment: Ok but that still brings me back to my issue of not being able to figure out how to calculate  the life span. @ChrisStratton

Comment: Divide the (milli) amp hour capacity by the current draw in operation as a starting point.  For more precision you'll have to look at the usable energy available at various current draw levels, and likely that the current drawn varies with dropping voltage, and of course the fact that below a certain voltage the remaining energy probably won't be usable.

Comment: @VladislavMartin Guilty as charged. I updated my question with that info.

Comment: I think this is a fine question! I just noticed that a lot of what I read here I had already read on Reddit, and I thought you'd want to avoid having the same stuff regurgitated at you here, too.

Answer (score 4):

In an ideal world your 9 V battery would deliver 500 mAh at 9 V exactly and then quit. The units give you a clue - current x time = 500 mAh. If you know your current draw you can work out the number of hours the battery can deliver this for. e.g., If your load is 25 mA then \$ h = \frac {mAh}{mA} = \frac {500}{25} = 20 \; h \$.

[image]

*Figure 1. Source: [PowerStream Technologies](https://www.powerstream.com/9-v-batteries.htm).*

Bear in mind that the mAh rating is measured at one particular discharge rate - probably the one that gives the highest rating and may differ from manufacturer to manufacturer. Capacity changes with temperature too. See the link above.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those problems that is best tested experimentally...

Reason being is quoted capacity of a battery is specific to a certain discharge rate, and obviously as the voltage of the cells in the battery drop, combined with sag due to current draw, the usable life of the battery really becomes application specific.

For the cost of (assuming pp3) one or a few batteries i would do whatever you propose and test it out. Far easier and more accurate than speculative calculation, in this case.

The setup you propose seems flawed as you will waste significant energy in the resistor. As commented i would suggest either a more suitable cell or some kind of regulation down to the required voltage, if you need to use a 9v cell. A buck will be more efficient than a linear reg in this case.